# 8 abdominal muscles but 10 pack

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles

[image]

Simple question, how is it possible that there are people who appear to have 10 pack abdominal muscles while the human body has only eight?

Comment: I've seen use of word **6** (six) packs in advertisements. Never heard about 10 packs.

Comment: While each muscle has a single "belly", many have multiple "heads". That is, portions of the muscle attach at different locations. These attachments follow, as separate bundles, down into the belly of the muscle. Biceps, for example, have two heads. I suspect it's possible these may appear as different bulges in a well developed gym rat.

Answer (score 5):

The only "way" someone can have a 8-pack or 10-pack is due to genetics. Across the rectus abdominis muscle you have either 3 or 4 tendinous bands going over it, consequently resulting in either a 8 or 10 pack.